# TextChanged Event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

In my single web application, only the Page_Load(...) event is firing. I've tried using the text change event below (auto generated by double clicking the textbox):

```
protected void txtBuyerExtension_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

But nothing happens. It does that for every control... the only event that fires is Page_Load. How come it is doing this?

Comment: What is in ASPX page ? are you sure you have the event specified in ASPX ? Could you post part of ASPX page for `txtBuyerExtension` ?

Comment: The ASPX is as follows: `<asp:TextBox ID="txtBuyerExtension" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtBuyerExtension_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: @duckwizzle - Post that as an answer - you beat me to it ;)

Comment: Make sure to set the Auto-Post back property to true on that control as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `AutoPostBack="True"`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBuyerExtension" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtBuyerExtension_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the AutoPostBack property to enable TextChange event.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBuyerExtension" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtBuyerExtension_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

And once you change the focus from TextBox this event will fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" CssClass="textbox1" placeholder="Search.." AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
                            OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```