# The TextChanged event is never triggered [MAUI]

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I want to make sure that as soon as my Entry has a modification (while writing) it calls the `TextChanged` event. But what happens is that the event is never called. I saw on [ASP.NET it is necessary to put AutoPostBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311048/textchanged-event-is-not-firing) is there something similar to add ? Or is it another thing ?

**Xaml**

```xml
<Entry
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    x:Name="inputUser"
    FontSize="16"
    Text="{Binding Input}"
    Opacity="1.0001"
    Focused="inputUser_Focused"
    TextChanged="inputUser_TextChanged"/>
```

**C#**

```cs
void inputUser_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string oldText = e.OldTextValue;
    string newText = e.NewTextValue;
    if (newText.Length < oldText.Length)
    {
        int diff = oldText.Length - newText.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
        {
            DeleteCommandExecute(null);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int diff = newText.Length - oldText.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
        {
            if (newText[oldText.Length+1].ToString()=="*"|| newText[oldText.Length + 1].ToString() == "/"||newText[oldText.Length + 1].ToString() == "+" || newText[oldText.Length + 1].ToString() == "-")
            {
                AddOperatorExecute(newText[oldText.Length + 1].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                AddNumberExecute(newText[oldText.Length + 1].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have looks correct. Testing on which platform/device/emulator? Breakpoint in method is not reached? Any message in Output pane similar to can’t find inputuser_textchanged?

Comment: I'm testing on windows and yes the breakpoints are never reached, there is no message the function is well found

Comment: Could you tell us the version of your visual studio ? We need more information to investigate the problem because your code totally looks no problem .

Comment: its 17.3.0 preview 1.1

Comment: I've upgraded my visual studio to `17.3.0 preview 1.1` and test with your code it runs well , the method is triggered as expected , could you  provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here ?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing Text binding to "Input".
TextChanged event is strangely incompatible with text binding.

Comment: It would be useful to provide more details and explain your answer. How does this solve the OP's problem?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'll be doing a bit of gravedigging, but it turns out @Peppegio74 identified the issue in here, and I have some extra remarks to bring.

It seems indeed TextChanged event is not working properly (simply not called at all, I tried adding a Breakpoint in the event) when the Entry has Text property bound to something. I had the same problem and when I removed the Binding on my own code the Event was once again called.

I noticed something interesting, in my project I have 3 Entries of this type, and the only one not working is always the first one (tested by commenting the other events).